# Woocommerce - Change font size for price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to make the font-size of the prices on [this](http://happyhealthymarket.com/) page larger and the prices on the related products seen [here](http://www.happyhealthymarket.com/product/live-american-lobster/). Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. Add following code to style.css

```
ul.products li.product .price
{
font-size: 40px;
}
```